# HttpClient StreamContent append filename twice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, content-type, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am using Microsoft Http Client Libraries to make a multipart request from Windows Phone 8 to the server. It contains a String content having json string and a Stream Content having image stream.
Now i get the status OK and request hits on the server. but the logs says the server is not able to get the file name of the image.

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "files", fileName);
```

where the photoStream is the image stream, "files" is the name of content and file name is the name of the image file.

So the header value must be:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=files; filename=image123.jpg
```

but actually it is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=files; filename=image123.jpg; filename*=utf-8''image123.jpg
```

Why it is appending the "`; filename*=utf-8''image123.jpg`" part.
Is it an issue?

Please let me know any reasons/possibility that i am not able to upload image from WP8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    content.Add(CreateFileContent(imageStream, fileName, "image/jpeg"));
}

private StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
    { 
        Name = "\"files\"", 
        FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
    };
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);            
    return fileContent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a problem when connecting to Campfire's API, who strictly reads the 'filename' property and will fail if you specify a UTF8 file name along with the stardard file name. Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Really helped.

Comment: Thanks!!! it took me quite some time to find a solution for this issue, really appreciated for sharing this tip

Answer (score 0):

For me, using HttpStringContent instead of StreamContent, Damith's solution did not work out but at the end I found this one:

```js
var fd = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
var file = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent(fs);
file.headers.contentType = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
fd.add(file);
file.headers.contentDisposition = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue.parse("form-data; name=\"your_form_name\"; filename=\"your_file_name\"");
```

Attention: it is abolute essential that you set contentDisposition after adding the file, otherwise the header will be overwritten by "form-data".

Answer (score -3):

My simple solution:

```
HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(xmlTmpFile, FileMode.Open));
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "xml", Path.GetFileName(xmlTmpFile));
fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileNameStar = null;
```