# .NET Core 3.1 Web API - The Content-Length is coming 0 when large data is sent in response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that can return large data of around 250MB. The data is coming from SQL so it cannot be referenced via hyperlinks. The client I am using is `HttpClient` on the calling application. It is not giving any error in response.

When it returns smaller data around 40MB, I get Status Code 200 in response. The Content-Length has some value. The `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` has the content.

But when it returns large data of around 150MB, I get Status Code 200 in response. The Content-Length is 0. The `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` has empty value.

Is there any limit on the response data size in Web API?

Comment: HI,@Reyan Chougle , Response have not limit the size, you can use postman to test the api (change the default  maximum size in postman because the default  maximum size in postman is 50MB), if the postman can receive the file successfully, The problem may be the defualt limit size of  file in upload file in client, You can add `[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]` attribute to change the  the defualt limit size of  file(200MB) in client.

Comment: @XinranShen I know that the response does not have any limit. But then why I am getting empty response when server sends large data

Comment: Because the receive file has a size limit, You can use postman to test the response first.

Comment: @XinranShen I made the changes in Postman to receive data of any size but still the same behaviour :(

Comment: You can reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948506/send-large-file-from-webapi-content-length-is-0)